Wonder why I got downvoted?
It is about this post How come Gnome developers consider Ubuntu 22.04 too old to take up bug reports regarding it?, it shows -1 I wonder why and why in my setting it shows -2?

Ubuntu 24.04 was released today with the latest GNOME version. Try it. Perhaps the bugs you had experienced have already been fixed. Otherwise, now you can report them and the report will be taken seriously.

The post currently shows -1 vote. From Thomas' answer, you see how that -1 is actually a sum of 5 votes.
Here we are talking about votes.

In your reputation history, on your profile page, it shows -2 reputation points.
Here we are talking about deducted reputation points.


So that's the difference.
Each downvote a post ends up with, deducts 2 points of reputation from the author of the post.
If someone downvotes someone else, that action deducts 1 reputation point from the downvoter (to impose a cost on downvoting, and to so prevent abuse of the feature).

In case someone wonders it is best to keep quiet and do your search and do not ask questions ;) This is from 125 points in https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-down
Downvotes remove 2 reputation from the post owner.
Downvotes on answers remove 1 reputation from you, the voter.
Downvotes on questions are free.
You can vote 30 times per UTC day. You get an additional 10 votes on questions only.

So, the vote score you see is the combination of upvotes and downvotes.
You have two upvotes and three downvotes on your question, for a total of -1 score.  I've even screenshot the current vote counts (visible at 1000 reputation points):

If somewhere it says -2 on the screen for you, it's incorrect, and you may have a cached page view or something in your browser cache you have to clear out.

Unless you're talking about your reputation page in which case every downvote you receive is a -2 hit to your reputation.  THAT is different from the vote count.

I am still learning, is adding pictures disabled in questions here? Did i by mistake opened the closed question? I tried with another browser and it was the same, -2 in my settings, and it shows only -1 . not the picture you pasted, No vote summeries except -1.

@amar seeing the vote counts in detail —upvotes separated from downvotes— is a user privilege that is granted at 1000 reputation points. It's shown here: https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges Look in the column at the 1000 points — it says: "Established user" and "You've been around for a while; see vote counts".
